# How To Add Rows Table in RDLC VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc

Good Day Sir / Maam

I need help in Report Design in VB.NET . My Design need 25 rows But my data query in dataset has only or less than 25. My question is how to add extra blank rows in the table in my Report. See my picture Thanks !!!

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Please, share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, you only need 1 row in a tablix and based on your dataset the reporter will generate the correct amount of rows.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to fill your page with the a fixed amount of empty rows. There are however a couple of workarounds that can give you the desired result. And because you know the maximum amount of rows and that number is relatively low, you could even do it manually.

1. *Using lines*: You could add lines on your report body in the place where the table borders would normally go by using the report item `Line`.
   This might be tricky for the horizontal borders, but you could simply ignore those and only add the vertical lines for column borders and the horizontal bottom line of the wanted table size. This would give a nice outline of the table without having to do any work.
2. *Automated approach:* Before sending the dataset to your reporter, you can get the number of rows. You can calculate the difference with the desired number of rows (`25 - length dataset`)  which you can use for 2 possible solutions.

   - You can create a number of empty objects, or simply the object with only empty strings for values, equal to that difference. Then add these objects to your original dataset which will cause the total amount of rows be the required size.
     When the reporter generates the table, empty rows will be printed in place of these objects.
   - You can create a new list with that length. you fill this list with empty strings and send it as a second datasource to your reporter.
     In the report designer you add a second table exactly below your original table, with the same amount of columns and without a header, for your new second dataset.
     This will cause the reporter to generate the correct amount of empty rows just below your original table.
3. *Manual approach*: Add the wanted amount of rows to the table, just below your row containing the data. (In your example this would be 25 empty rows).
   For each row you will need to define an expression for the `Hidden` property to determine when to show the row.

   > =IIF(Count(Fields!ID.Value,"DatasetName") < **RowNumer** , False, True)

   So basically if the total number of rows in the dataset is lower than the empty rows position (*RowNumber*), the row will be displayed. Else that row will be hidden.
   Applied to each row would look like this:

   ```
   //Empty Row 1  
   =IIF(Count(Fields!ID.Value,"DatasetName") < 1, False, True) 

   //Empty Row 2
   =IIF(Count(Fields!ID.Value,"DatasetName") < 2, False, True)

   //... Empry Row 3 to 24

   //Empty Row 25
   =IIF(Count(Fields!ID.Value,"DatasetName") < 25, False, True)
   ```

Now you have 3 possibilities to chose from.
The automated approach is perhaps slightly more clean but would require you to do the necessary preparations in code before sending it to the reporter.
The manual approach might look a little robust but with a low number of rows it is manageable and easily added to the design without needing to change anything to the code.